# AWS EC2 RDP stopped working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp

I'm trying to connect to a Windows instance in EC2 through RDP but it gives me the message

- Remote Desktop to server is not enabled
- The remote Computer is turned off
- The remote computer is not available on the network.

The weird thing is that the connection worked fine last week and nothing has changed. 
The instance can be reached through a VPN connection. I think this is the problem because I have read many posts and everything seems setted up correctly (for example the RDP port on the security group and other things)

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Describe in more detail what works and what doesn't.

Comment: I connect to the vpn as usual using windows and I add the route from the prompt. The connection status says connected but no network access. Is it normal? That was I did since last week but and I just needed to connect the RD and everything worked fine. Now when I try to connect to the private IP address it gives that error message

Answer (score 0):

As you have quoted it worked last week but now, these are the things which you can check

1. Your public IP may be changed i.e. In the RD port - IP Access for the Instance in Security Group; RD port could have been to your old IP and now your IP could have been changed, recheck your public IP and verify that against that in SG of the Instance
2. As it is from VPC, the Security Group of the Instances can be completely changed / RD rules removed
3. Your instance's Firewall is enabled and blocking
4. Your corporate firewall is blocking to connect to your instance.
5. Attach an Elastic IP and re-check.

Comment: 1. I think that all IP are allowed to connect to RD port.

Comment: 2.There is the RD rule on the instance I need to connect

Comment: 3.-4. I don't know how to deal with it. But why it should be changed?

Comment: 5. It is already attached to an Elastic IP. Do I need to create a new one?